# Implementing jwilhem's slider on a Mapbox map in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, leaflet, mapbox, jquery-ui-slider

Trying to implement [D Wilhem's Leaflet Slider](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider), a front end to the [JQuery UI slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) in Rails. I get the error `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: L`. I've looked at lots of discussions and imagine I've mixed up my syntax. The page loads and 1) my data shows up, 2) the slider control shows up, but the slider doesn't function and I get then aforementioned error.

```
 function makeMap() {
   L.mapbox.accessToken = $('body').data("mapboxToken");

   var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mtnbiker.d7jfhf8u') // Was: mapbox.streets
              .setView([34.040951, -118.258579], 13);

   L.control.fullscreen().addTo(map);

   var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
                     .loadURL('map/point_data.geojson')
                     .addTo(map);

   var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
                        .loadURL('map/line_data.geojson')
                         .addTo(map);

   var sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({range: true, alwaysShowDate: true, timeStrLength: 10, layer: featureLayer});

   map.addControl(sliderControl); 

   sliderControl.startSlider();

   $('#slider-timestamp').html(options.markers[ui.value].feature.properties.time.substr(0, 10)); 

   featureLayer.on('ready', function(e) {
     map.fitBounds(featureLayer.getBounds());
   });
  }
```

`application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require 'leaflet.js'
//= require leaflet
//= require_tree .
```

### The map loads with data (points and lines) and non-functioning slider at localhost. Points are loading at Heroku, but not the lines nor slider.  https://secure-shore-68966.herokuapp.com/map.

Answer:
After weeks of trying different things, a friend from MaptimeLA was able to sit down with me at a meeting and found a type. She is very familiar with Rails and debugging. 
application.js was:

```
//  require jquery.ui
//  require jquery.ui.widget
```

Fixed

```
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.ui.widget
```

Thanks to all who chimed in.

All the code is at https://bitbucket.org/MtnBiker/crores5/.

PS. I can't see the checkbox to say I want to answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code in the link, you load the following scripts in this order:

```
<script src="/assets/application-665a36b2268b441400787c68e9f08977c28cc33814ce32a46439c27016b720ec.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.4/mapbox.js"></script>
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-fullscreen/v1.0.1/Leaflet.fullscreen.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider/master/SliderControl.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.2/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

I suspect that something is loading out of order or that `L` is being dropped someplace. Also I do not see where the core jQuery is being loaded.

Looking at the [Demo](http://dwilhelm89.github.io/LeafletSlider/), they load the following:

```
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.2/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider/master/SliderControl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So I think all you're missing is the core jQuery and Maybe the LeafletJS. Here is a working JSFiddle based on the example they provide.

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/sr0sjzk2/

Comment: Thank you. I'll look more at that. In fact I've been working through the asset management since I posted. I don't understand the hierarchy, but am trying to sort it out. Also working to better figure out how to use Dev Tools in the browser to see what's loading. Will be at least a day before I expect to make much progress. The map and points are now loading at Heroku, but not the lines nor the slider. Maps, points, and slider load on localhost, but the slider is not functioning with a new error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_leaflet_id' of undefined(…)`.

Comment: @Greg your Datapoints are not loading fully. I see a 500 Error in response to one of the GET requests in AJAX. This will cascade into variables that are not properly populated (Undefined) resulting in errors in your code. Your code will run up to these points and either halt or operate with strangeness.

Comment: I see that jQuery isn't there. It's on localhost, so something is different about Heroku. I'll look into that. Thank you

Comment: I think jQuery is included in https://secure-shore-68966.herokuapp.com/assets/application-665a36b2268b441400787c68e9f08977c28cc33814ce32a46439c27016b720ec.js. I looked for parts of jQuery 2.2.2 in that and found pieces that looked similar. Rails puts assets that are listed in certain places all together. Have to look at more of the page loading.

Comment: @Greg not seeing any loading issues now. Also seeing al the connection lines.

Comment: Thanks for checking. It's crazy. I see it fine on Safari, but not Chrome. And doesn't work on localhost. I repushed to Heroku last night to make sure both Heroku and localhost were the same. I think this tells me I need to work through the assets, because I've made it too delicate.  And now I don't even see the scroll bar anywhere (Actually I just looked at the code and see a big problem—something got pasted in.. I  need to figure out if development mode (localhost) and production handle this differently. I have Rails Guides opened to Asset Pipeline and will work through it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer. But working through the asset pipeline in Rails and making changes I've eliminated the error. The problem was probably that in using various tutorial, I'd put in different versions of Leaflet or jQuery in different places in the Ruby on Rails app.

However the page still doesn't work correctly. I get `TypeError: $("#leaflet-slider").slider is not a function. (In '$("#leaflet-slider").slider', '$("#leaflet-slider").slider' is undefined)` error on localhost. The error is in D Wilhelm's SliderControl.js. On Heroku, no errors but no slider. I'll post a new question. https://secure-shore-68966.herokuapp.com/map.

Thank you Twisty for your help.